# Styling an extended native element in ShadowDOM

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I understand that in order to style elements from the ShadowDOM, the shadowDOM itself has to "know"
the element, thus be declared inside of it.
It works well for regular web components but i haven't found an answer to it weather it's the same for an extended
native element.
For example, I wanted to know if the code I wrote is the best way, i.e. the external p acting as container, or am i creating a redundant p element.

JavaScript:

```
class P_example extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
        <style>
        p{
            background-color: orangered;
            width: max-content;
        }
        </style>
        <p><slot>Some default</slot></p>
    `;
    this.shadowRoot.append();
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    //add styling class to the p element
  }
}
customElements.define("omer-p", P_example, { extends: "p" });
```

HTML:

```
<p is="omer-p">Some sample text</p>
```

Comment: Your ``<p>`` are **two different** elements; one in _lightDOM_ and one in _shadowDOM_

Comment: BTW Customized Built-In Elements (extending anything other than HTMLElement) will never work in Safari. Part of the spec Apple said they will (and rightly so) never implement